# First meeting with potential PhD supervisor

Tags: graduate-school

I have meeting with my potential supervisor in a few days. He already told me that I should prepare talk about my previous research and steps that I took. Do you have any advices how to be precise and short? I don't need to go into details since it will be a short meeting, but i still want to impress him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have a meeting with potential supervisors, I try to keep it short and simple, but here are what I usually mention:

1. Summary of past research experience and a notable project. I summarize what I do in that project; objective and outcome of the project.
2. (If it is asked) How familiar I am with the state of the art of the fields they are interested. How much I do like the topic. Relevant experience.
3. My self-study plan to cultivate necessary knowledge and skills before going to the graduate school.